# Highest Negative Value

Tags: python, python-3.x, user-input, highest

I don't understand why this doesn't work. I want to print the **highest negative value** from a series of user-inputted negative ints. E.g., user inputs: -1, -5, -3, program returns -1. But my program (below) is returning -5. Why is this? Is my code totally messed up? I know I can use a list and max way around it but I don't want to over-complicate the program.

```
x = 0
done = False
while not done:
    y = int(input("Enter another number (0 to end): "))
    num = y
    if num != 0:
        if num < x:
            x = num
    else:
        done = True
print(str(x))
```

Comment: Because -5 < -1?  That's what the highest negative value means. Do you want the smallest then? Reverse your operations

Comment: You are setting x to the lowest number, not the highest. Reverse the comparator in `if num < x`.

Comment: " I know I can use a list and max way around it but I don't want to over-complicate the program" *Your* way over-complicates the program. Using `max` would be a single line of code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your operator should be **greater than** `>`, not less than `<` in order to take the maximum value. Initializing to `-float('inf')` ensures the first negative value passes the condition:

```
x = -float('inf')
while True:
    num = int(input("Enter another number (0 to end): "))
    if num != 0:
        if num > x:
            x = num
    else:
        break
print(x)
```

You can drop the `done` variable by using a `while True...break` instead.

---

> I know I can use a list and max way around it but I don't want to
>   over-complicate the program.

You can do this in a single line using **[`iter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#iter)** with your **sentinel** `0` to call `input` repeatedly, collecting an *iterable* of negative numbers. [`map(int, ...)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map) converts the iterable items to ints while [`max`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#max) returns the maximum:

```
max(map(int, iter(input, '0')))
```

---

*Demo*:

```
>>> m = max(map(int, iter(input, '0')))
-3
-1
-4
-2
0
>>> m
-1
```

Comment: This is nice code. Thank you for explaining it and showing the one line example. That's impressive!

Answer (score 3):

Well the *highest* negative value is the same as the *maximum* value.

Now your loop invariant should be that `x` is the *thus far observed maximum value*. But you actually store the thus far observed *minimum value*: indeed if the new value is *less* than, you assign it to `x`.

So a quick fix is to change to comparison to `>`. But now the initial *maximum* will be `0`. We can change that, by setting the initial value to for instance `None`, and if `x` is `None`, set `x` to the entered value.

```
x = None
done = False
while not done:
    y = int(input("Enter another number (0 to end): "))
    num = y
    if num != 0:
        if x is None or num > x:
            x = num
    else:
        done = True
```

Comment: Good solution. Thank you! I was not familiar with using None but I will remember it now for future reference.

Answer (score 1):

You never compare the inputted value with the largest-negative-value so far. You also set your initial value to zero, which is not a suitable result value. One way to handle these is to replace your lines

```
if num < x
    x = num
```

with

```
if num < 0 and (x == 0 or x < num < 0):
  x = num
```

There are other ways, of course, including setting `x` to the smallest possible negative number. That would simplify your comparisons, since in my code above there is a check just for `x` never being set before.

Note that if there is no negative number input at all, the result is zero. That may or may not be what you want.

Answer (score 1):

Just use inbuilt `max` function to find maximum number

```
numbers = []
done = False
while not done:
    number = int(input("Enter another number (0 to end): "))
    if number < 0:
        numbers.append(number)
    else:
        done = True

print(max(numbers))
```